# How do you reference the workbook that called an Addin from the Addin in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2010, I have an Addin that is called from the Ribbon XML file from the main workbook.

How do I reference the workbook (I really need its path) that called the Addin from within the Addin?

For Example, I can use ThisWorkbook to reference the workbook with the code in it (in this case the Addin).  Is there anything similar to reference the calling workbook?

Answer (score 1):

If you know it's the Active workbook, which would be true if the user clicked a button, then you can use:

```
Activeworkbook.Fullname
```

You may have to store it in a workbook variable earlier if other workbooks become active before you're doing the processing in question.

Comment: The problem is that the Activeworkbook is the Addin, not the calling workbook.

Comment: Even immediately after the button on the ribbon is clicked?  Clearly, when it's clicked the workbook itself is active.  Maybe you could give a little more detail about what happens between the ribbon control being pressed (or whatever) and the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I can think of....

1.From the main add-in pass

```
ThisWorkbook.Name and/or ThisWorkbook.Path
```

or

2.Identify the Window/Class Name from API  see [Get Window Handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748968/cannot-change-excel-icon-in-taskbar-with-vba/5756624#5756624)